# SQL intersection - error in syntax

Tags: sql, hsqldb, intersect, libreoffice-base

I am trying search for flights departing from London and Arriving in Paris. The information about the cities are located in the Airport table, while the abbreviations for the departing and arriving airports are located in Flight.

Here's my code for the problem:

```
SELECT flightNo,flightCompany
FROM Flight
JOIN Airport
ON Airport.airportId=Flight.depAirport
WHERE Airport.city='London'

INTERSECT

SELECT flightNo,flightCompany
FROM Flight
JOIN Airport
ON Airport.airportId=Flight.arrAirport
WHERE Airport.city='Paris';
```

It returns 3 errors -

- SQL Status: HY000 Error code: 1000 Syntax error in SQL statement
- SQL Status: HY000 Error code: 1000
- SQL Status: HY000 Error code: 1000 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or SQL_TOKEN_LIKE

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Libreoffice

Comment: That is a client/front end tool, but which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I just have the tables imported into Libreoffice via an .odb file. It is not for any practical application - just looking for a solution to a question asked by our uni.

Comment: No idea. The code you have shown is valid SQL. So maybe whatever DBMS LibreOffice is using, it doesn't support that.

Comment: what is the syntax error?

Comment: Is this supposed to get flights that depart from London and arrive in Paris or any flight departing from London and any flight arriving in Paris?

Comment: It gives 3 errors - SQL Status: HY000
Error code: 1000

Syntax error in SQL statement

SQL Status: HY000
Error code: 1000

SQL Status: HY000
Error code: 1000

syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or SQL_TOKEN_LIKE

Comment: And what does the error say?

Comment: it is supposed to be all flights that are both departing from London and arriving in Paris.

Comment: That's all the info given in the errors.

Comment: Is it possible to add a couple of example rows from each of the tables to the question?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/97VxC those would be some examples

Comment: FWIW, when I run your query on the ANSI-compliant SQL DB that my company happens to use, I don't get any syntax errors, so it sounds like this issue could be a peculiarity with your particular back-end.

Comment: It sounds like you can get the error returned by the database engine by running the command using the "Run the SQL command directly" option in the "Edit" menu. Can you try that?

Comment: http://imgur.com/qTzbUok This would be the error.

Comment: And do those tables actually exist (do you get results for `select * from flight` and for `select * from airport`)?

Comment: Yes, for instance this query works:
SELECT Flight.flightNo, Flight.flightCompany, Flight.depAirport, Flight.arrAirport 
FROM Flight, Airport 
WHERE Flight.depAirport = Airport.airportId 
AND Airport.city = 'London';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about re-writing the query using `JOIN`s instead?

```
SELECT f.flightNo, f.flightCompany
FROM Flight f JOIN
     Airport ad
     ON ad.airportId = f.depAirport AND ad.city = 'London' JOIN
     Airport aa
     ON aa.airportId = f.arrAirport AND aa.city = 'Paris';
```

Or, using `EXISTS`?

```
SELECT f.*
FROM Flight f
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Airport ad
              WHERE ad.airportId = f.depAirport AND ad.city = 'London'
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Airport aa
              WHERE aa.airportId = f.arrAirport AND aa.city = 'Paris'
             );
```

Comment: I see how that might work, but for some reason it doesn't output any results (there is a combination of airports that should be shown).

Comment: I am unsure if I should be changing anything in the second code, as I am somewhat new to SQL, but copying and running it as written gives an error - the data content could not be loaded, Table not found in statement.

Comment: @Sick0ne . . . The second query had "airport".  Perhaps your database is case sensitive about table names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second query works as intended. Decided to go with the following though:
`SELECT F.flightNo,F.FlightCompany

FROM Flight F, Airport A1, Airport A2

WHERE (F.depAirport=A1.airportId AND A1.city='London')

AND (F.arrAirport=A2.airportId AND A2.city='Paris')`

Comment: @Sick0ne . . . You should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax:  never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting rules and case sensitivity using the default LibreOffice Base / HSQLDB 1.8 setup are tricky.  Here is what you need to do:

```
SELECT "flightNo","flightCompany"
FROM "Flight"
JOIN "Airport"
ON "Airport"."airportId"="Flight"."depAirport"
WHERE "Airport"."city"='London'
INTERSECT
SELECT "flightNo","flightCompany"
FROM "Flight"
JOIN "Airport"
ON "Airport"."airportId"="Flight"."arrAirport"
WHERE "Airport"."city"='Paris';
```

Or better, modify Gordon's answer as follows:

```
SELECT F."flightNo", F."flightCompany"
FROM "Flight" F JOIN
     "Airport" AD
     ON AD."airportId" = F."depAirport" AND AD."city" = 'London' JOIN
     "Airport" AA
     ON AA."airportId" = F."arrAirport" AND AA."city" = 'Paris';
```

Comment: See, this is what Libre Office does automatically for you. If you save a file, it's going to add the quotation marks by itself - if you open your query again, it's going to look that way.
Decided to go with this in the end (and yes, Gordon's second code works):
`SELECT F.flightNo,F.FlightCompany
FROM Flight F, Airport A1, Airport A2
WHERE (F.depAirport=A1.airportId AND A1.city='London')
AND (F.arrAirport=A2.airportId AND A2.city='Paris')`